# sqlite where clause "AND" and "IN"

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sql-delete

**Objective**:
I am trying to do bulk delete in sqlite table, instead of deleting each data with for loop. So, I am trying to use `"IN"`.

**Case**:
I have two parameters in executing the query. First is `type` and second is `order_id`. I want to delete data where the `type` is `"order_book"` and `order_id` are `["B001", "B002", ...]`.

**What I've try but not working**:

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'dbname.db', location: 'default' }).executeSql("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE type='order_book' AND order_id IN ('B001', 'B002')", [], (res) => { console.log(res.rows); });
// => this is not work
```

**What I've try and works, but, it miss the type parameter**:

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'dbname.db', location: 'default' }).executeSql("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE order_id IN ('B001', 'B002')", [], (res) => { console.log(res.rows); });
// => data with order_id B001 and B002 deleted
```

So, whats wrong here? I need to also define what is the `type` because different `type` may have same `order_id` (don't ask why this is happen ...)

Thanks in advance for anyhelp!

Comment: The query looks OK so I assume it is the data that is stored against `type`. Note that SQLlite's comparison may be case sensitive. You could check against the data stored or compare strings like this:  WHERE type='order_book' COLLATE NOCASE

Comment: @J.R. did you mean the query should be like this? => window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'dbname.db', location: 'default' }).executeSql("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE type='order_book' COLLATE NOCASE AND order_id IN ('B001', 'B002')", [], (res) => { console.log(res.rows); });

Comment: @J.R. well, thats working mate. But, I wanna know why COLLATE NOCASE works? I mean, I found that sqlite is case sensitive but I am 100% sure that the data is all in lower case. So, I think I dont have to make the query to be case insensitive.

Comment: Yes. You could also check whether type data is stored in mixed case or upper case and whether you can find 'order_book' in your table.

Comment: @J.R. and also, could you please help me how to pass the parameter inside the []? I mean, I pass the value parameter directly inside the query string, like type='order_book'. What in my mind is to make it like this => window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'dbname.db', location: 'default' }).executeSql("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE type=? COLLATE NOCASE AND order_id IN (?)", ['order_book', ['B001', 'B002'] ], (res) => { console.log(res.rows); }); but this is not working.

Comment: Not sure... does 'B001, B002' (rather than array) work?

Comment: @J.R. idk, what I wanna achieve is create a variable contain the query online and all the value parameter in the query set to be like order_book=? and receive the data from other function. So, I could try manipulate the data so the single query will work. But, Idk the right query and the format of the parameter that the query could receive

Comment: @J.R. please answer the question by mentioning that COLLATE NOCASE. I'll accept it as the answer. Cause thats actually the answer of my initial question. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Akza, will do. What I meant previously was to pass a string 'B001, B002' rather than array; that string can be in a variable. I'm not sure about it though, possibly post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is stored in mixed case or upper case in the `type` column then SQLite's case sensitive comparison will not find it. You could check against the data stored or compare strings like this:

```
WHERE type='order_book' COLLATE NOCASE ...
```